# Ranking and storing scores to a database

Tags: php

I am developing a small website with PHP and am trying to receive user exam scores from the database. I rank it based on the highest score and then store the ranking to the database based on the `user_id` returned from the database with the score.

I have finished the code but it's too long. I need optimizations and reviews.

```
//=============init connection
$dbc = new mysqli('localhost','root','','test');


//==================database========================
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`score` int(11) NOT NULL,
`subposition` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;


//=========================functions=======================
function gradeScoreFormula($score1, $score2)
{
if ($score1 > $score2)
{
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}

function gradeScore(array $values,$functionName, $dbc)
{
$newArr = array();
$dbc->autocommit(false);

uasort($values, $functionName);
$size = count($values);

foreach ($values as $k => $v)
{
    $newArr[] = array($k  => $v);
}

$reversedArr = array_reverse($newArr);
$complete = 0;
for($i=0; $i < $size; $i++)
{
    //echo 'POS = '.$a = $i + 1 .' --> ';
    $position = $a = $i + 1;
    foreach($reversedArr[$i] as $k => $v)
    {
        //echo "UID = ".$k."----------> score = ".$v.'<br>';
        $q = "UPDATE USERS set subposition = $position WHERE uid = $k AND score = $v";
        $r = $dbc->query($q);
        if ($dbc->affected_rows)
        {
            $complete +=1;
        }
    }
}

if ($complete == $size)
{
    $dbc->commit();
    echo 'succesfully stored';
}else{
    $dbc->rollback();
    echo 'not stored try again';
}
$dbc->autocommit(true);
}

//===============================program start========================
$q1 = "SELECT uid, score FROM users";
$r1 = $dbc->query($q1);
$returnedVal = [];

while(list($id, $scores) = $r1->fetch_array())
{
$returnedVal[$id] = $scores;
}

print_r($returnedVal);

gradeScore($returnedVal,'gradeScoreFormula', $dbc);
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Formatting**

- your indentation is off, making your code hard to read.
- it is customary to put the opening curly bracket on the same line as the statement it belongs to (except for functions and classes).
- `if (cond) return true; else return false;` can be written as `return cond`.
- Your spacing is not consistent (use an IDE to fix this - and most other formatting issues - easily).

If we fix these issues, the first function for example would look like this:

```
function gradeScoreFormula($score1, $score2)
{
    return $score1 > $score2;
}
```

**Naming**

- `gradeScoreFormula` is quite specific for such a generic function, yet it doesn't really tell me anything about what the function actually does. `isLargerThan` might be better. [Although the function seems all wrong anyways. All the `sort` functions expect the function to return an integer; in that case, you could simply call the function `compare`]

**Security**

You should use prepared statements, as you may otherwise be vulnerable to second order SQL injection.

Even if the score and/or uid values in the users table are not currently user input, they may be in the future.

Additionally, prepared statements may increase performance in this case, as the query would only need to be prepared once.

**Misc**

- `WHERE uid = $k AND score = $v` seems odd to me. Why are you checking for the score as well? If there is a reason, I would add a comment about it. If there is no reason, I would remove that check; the primary id should be enough, as far as I can tell.
- why have `position` and `a`? It doesn't seem necessary to have two variables here. For that matter, it doesn't seem necessary to have either one, you could simply use `i + 1` directly in the query.
- Your `foreach($reversedArr[$i] as $k => $v)` is confusing and unnecessary. You only have it to access the key and value of a one-entry array. If you need the key, you can use the `key` function.

**Complexity**

Your code is indeed overly complex, mainly because you perform unnecessary and complex transformations between data structures and because you are not using the correct functions.

The core of your program could be as simple as this:

```
function gradeScore(array $values, $dbc)
{
    arsort($values);

    $position = 0;
    $query = "UPDATE users set subposition = ? WHERE uid = ?";
    $statement = $dbc->prepare($query);
    foreach($values as $id => $score) {
        $position++;
        $statement->bind_param("ss", $position, $id);
        $result = $statement->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: the core program you suggested is there any way you can determine if all insertions were completed without an error?

Comment: @SylvesterHilary sure, you can check `$result`, it will be false if there was an error. (I left out error checking for clarity).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everything @tim put down and would just add a few more comments.

**Good practices**

- Don't leave stray, commented-out `echo` statements in your code. This is sloppy, makes your code more difficult to read, and might get uncommented accidentally when you are in production. When I am still trouble-shooting a project but have put it into use, I like to have some optional `loquacious` variable I can set to true or false to indicate whether I want logged/echoed statements. Consider doing something like this instead if you are not ready to delete these `echo` statements.

  `if($loquacious) echo ....`

  Related to this, what's up with the `print_r` statement at the bottom of your code. Is this production or debugging code? I can't tell, and that's not good.
- If all you do in a function is evaluate a boolean, you should just return that evaluation directly. In particular, I am referring to `gradeScoreFormula` which can be rewritten more succinctly and clearly as the following:

  `function gradeScoreFormula($score1, $score2)
  {
      return ($score1 > $score2)
  }`

  I would also ask whether you really need a function for this when all it does is evaluate a boolean. Relatedly the name is confusing and does not indicate what the function is doing. You should rename this something like `function isGreater` with more generalized variable names.
- You use `$newArr[] = array($k => $v)`, which I don't see too often and which I'm guessing most programmers don't see too often. Why not use `array_push` if you want an array of arrays? Also why do you want an array of arrays? Why not just use  `$newArr[$k] = $v` ?
- My understanding is that [`PDO`s](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) are the industry standard now, so you should really use them to manage database connections. They're not syntactically all that different, and they make your code more portable/maintainable.
- Another good rule of thumb is that you should have the database do as much work as possible (of course there are use cases where this isn't true, but it generally is). I didn't entirely follow your code, but why are you reversing an array? Does that mean you got the results from the database in the opposite order of what you want? If so, modify your database query so that your webserver can avoid unnecessary work.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by "have some optional loquacious variable I can set to true or false to indicate whether I want logged/echoed statements." do you mind explaining a little more

Comment: Sure. People might more often call it a logging variable. In my example above, I would have a config file included that establishes a variable $loquacious. I set it to TRUE when I want to see echo/log statements and false when I don't. This way you can easily turn logging off. Does that make sense?